# Mocking subclass items with mockito in java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, mockito

I have written a testclass for a baseclass that uses a factory. I `@Mock`ed the factory to return a Mock object.
It looks sort of like this.

```
class BaseClass{
  SomeFactory factory;

  public BaseClass(SomeFactory factory){
    this.factory=factory;
  }


  public void parse(){
     factory.createSomething();
  }
}
```

Now my (working) testclass looks like this.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BaseTest {
  @Mock
  SomeFactory factory;
  @Mock
  SomeCreation crateation;

  BaseClass subject;



  @Before 
  public void setUp(){
    when(factory.createSomething()).thenReturn(someCreation);
    subject = new BaseClass(factory);
  }

  @Test
  testParse(){
    subject.Parse();
    verify(factory).createSomething();
  }
 }
```

This all works fine, but now i have extended `BaseClass` (lets call it `SubClass`) and added some functionality. My `SubClass` also uses an extended factory (`SubFactory`). So i also want to extend `BaseTest` and run the same tests, because it does the exact same thing and something extra.

so i overrode the `setUp()` like so:

```
class SubTest extends BaseTest{

  @Mock
  SubFactory subFactory;
  @Mock
  Something something;

  @Override 
  public void setUp(){

    when(subFactory.createSomething()).thenReturn(
    factory = subFactory;
    subject = new SubClass(subFactory);
   } 
 }
```

This however doesn't work, because in the baseclass it throws an `UnfinishedVerificationException` saying:

```
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
```

pointing to the verify in the `BaseClass`.

Any ideas on how to structure my test-cases that allows me to test the `SubClass` with the same tests as `BaseClass`?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not extend test cases! Even though there will be (lots of) duplicated code, it's easier to be read and followed.

So, the subclass test should **not** extend the `BaseClass` test, but rather re-use the tests on the functionality, which will not be overwritten in the subclass. Also, a getter for the `factory` would be needed to better customize the behavior on the mocked factory:

```
class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    SubClass(SubFactory factory) {
        super(factory);
    }

    SubFactory getFactory() { return factory; }

    public void parse() {
       getFactory().createSomething();
    }
}

class SubTest {

  @Mock
  SubFactory subFactory;

  @Mock
  Something something;

  @Mock
  SubCreation someSubCreation;

  SubClass subject = new SubClass(subFactory);

  public void setUp() {
    when(subFactory.createSomething()).thenReturn(someSubCreation);
  }

}
```

Comment: So you are saying i should copy-paste all my test-methods?

Comment: Yes. But only those, which test functionality that will be same for the subclass. And if these tests fail for the subclass, then the subclass overwrites this functionality and new test should be introduced instead.

Comment: Well, The point is that this is a homework assignment on testing code-quality. So i don't think they will like it if i copy paste a whole class. Because in the real code i actualy have more tests.

Comment: Unit-tests should not be a subject of review (when reviewing code quality). Of course, they should follow some basic rules, but it's not recommended to build hierarchies of tests (by extending and overriding). Unit-tests should be single and not bound to other unit-tests. When I first heard this I was shocked, too, but actually it makes sense.

Comment: For further info, you can checkout this article: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/unit-testing/3-reasons-why-we-should-not-use-inheritance-in-our-tests/

Comment: I see your point, maybe better to create a utils test class instead of inheritance or copy-paste

Comment: I don't agree on that. I still very much prefer having all the code, related to a single test-case in a single method. Unit-tests are not only executable pieces that verify the correctness of something, they also have a documentation purpose (I call them "executable documentation"), because they are a way to get familiar what the class under test does, without having to get familiar with implementation details. Moving pieces from the method here and there just complicates the test and the test-case method can become difficult to be adjusted after possible specification changes.

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov I downvoted it by mistake and now the web doesnt allow me  to upvote. Plz can you edit somehow so I can upvote?